# Is there a short form of a polynomial function applied to itself $i$-times?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, summation, sequence-of-function

Given a polynomial $f$ of degree $m$:
$$f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{m} a_jx^j$$

Now this polynomial is applied to itself $f(f(f(f...(f(x))))$ for $i$($-1$) times $->f^i(x)$. The resulting function is a polynomial as well but has a degree of $m^i$

$$f^1(x)=f(x)$$
$$f^2(x)=f(f(x))$$
$$f^i(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{m^i} b_{i,k}x^k$$

Is there a short form for each coefficient? And with this a short form of $f^i(x)$?

### Trials so far

It should look something like (other form also possible):
$$b_{i,k} = \sum_{j=0}^{m^i} \prod^?_? a_j^?$$

It starts with:
(edit: also complicated)

and ends with:
$$b_{i,m^i} = a_m^i$$

For other $k$ it gets complicated.

---

Alternative form: 
$$f^i(x) =\sum_{j=0}^m a_j [..\text{i times sum total}...\sum_{j=0}^m a_j\{\sum_{j=0}^m a_j(\sum_{j=0}^m a_jx^j)^j\}^j]$$

Comment: The degree is $m^i$, not $i\cdot m$.

Comment: My attempt: $b_{i, 0} = f(f(\cdots(f(0))))  = a_0^i$; for higher k using derivatives may help. My guess is that the chain rule gives you the product-like expression.

Comment: @metamorphy oh dear, ty for hint. I changed it.

Comment: Begin by doing a simple case.  $f(f(x))$.  I think that by itself will be so complicated that you will give up on the general project.

Comment: @GEdgar Did some tests with $m=3$ and $i=3$. Fully enrolled it had over 25.000 characters. It's complicated but it has some internal structure (repeated binomial coefficient). There might be some close form.